# How to use additional icons in Sencha Touch tabBar?

Tags: sencha-touch, pictos

With Sencha Touch, i want to use some of the icons in the directory `resources/themes/images/default/pictos/` for iconCls in my footer navigation.  But from what I've read, it says I need to set up a ruby on rails server just to compile the right stylesheets and javascript files to use them?

I don't have the least bit knowledge of how to set up my own servers or set up my own RoR server.  Is there anyway else to do this?  I just want 3 icons from that directory...setting up a whole server seems  a bit overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the following CSS

```css
/* TV icon for Videos */
/* USED IN SENCHA TOUCH V2*/
.x-tab .x-button-icon.tv,.x-button .x-button-icon.x-icon-mask.tv{-webkit-mask-image:url(/resources/themes/images/default/pictos/TV.png)}
```

Actually... to be perfectly honest, I didn't map my CSS to the image, but rather converted the image to Base64 and embedded it in the CSS. The reason for this was that I only needed 4 of the icons and I didn't want to move them all around every time.

```css
/* TV icon for Videos */
/* USED IN SENCHA TOUCH V2*/
.x-tab .x-button-icon.tv,.x-button .x-button-icon.x-icon-mask.tv{-webkit-mask-image:url(data:image/png;base64,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);}
```

Now, when you're creating your TabPanel you want do do something along these lines.

```js
    Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
        fullscreen: true,
        tabBar: {
            docked: 'bottom',
            layout: {
                pack: 'center'
            }
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'Video',
            iconCls: 'tv' // the icon class string is appended to the CSS 
                          // '.x-icon-mask.[iconCls string]' 
                          // in this case 
                          // '.x-icon-mask.tv'
                          // as seen in the CSS above
        }]
    });
```

---

### EDIT

Looking over my old Sencha Touch V1 code base (as per your comment below) you will want to use the following CSS for Sencha Touch V1

```css
/* TV icon for Videos */
/* USED IN SENCHA TOUCH V1*/
.x-tab img.tv,.x-button img.x-icon-mask.tv{-webkit-mask-image:url('/resources/themes/images/default/pictos/TV.png');}
```

Comment: Thank you, the line of css you wrote didn't work for me, maybe because i'm using a different version of sencha touch.  However, after poking around the css file, I copied a related CSS rulet and did this `.x-tab img.tv,.x-button img.x-icon-mask.tv {-webkit-mask-image:url(resources/themes/images/default/pictos/tv.png)}`.  So I used your idea, but needed to change the css selector a bit.

Comment: Yeah that could be. I figured it out by poking around the existing CSS. I'm currently working with ST2 Beta2

Comment: The recommended way is to use compass. See [TDeBailleul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9301471/478536)

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you need to install Ruby and RubyGems (only if you're on Windows because they are pre bundled on Mac)

Then you just need to open the right scss file in touch/resources/sass (depending on what them you're using) and to add the following line to it :

```
@include pictos-iconmask(PICTOS_NAME);
```

Finally you need to open a terminal in that folder and to execute the following command :

```
compass compile // Run it every time you change something in the .scss
```

or

```
compass watch // Will automatically recompile every time you save
```

[More information about Sencha-Touch Theming here](http://www.sencha.com/blog/an-introduction-to-theming-sencha-touch)